# Joomla redirecting to /index.php// every site even Administrator. Causes Redirect Loop

Tags: joomla-3.x

I haven't changed anything in my files nor settings but it just started to redirect index.php// it is weird because I haven't touched a file and it started randomly. Every site redirects even the administrator to index.php//.

Can anyone help me? I don't have anything in my htaccess.

Comment: I suggest you ask your hoster.
If you haven't changed anything and it started out of nowhere chances are high your hoster changed something.
Or you got hacked and the hacker changed something.

Comment: Do you have a second layer login in Admin area? You can try disable the plugin direct in database #__extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too.
It was caused by two plugins that were checking the same user details and  were redirecting in a manner that seemed random.

I would start by thinking and disabling any recently installed or updated plugins.

If you cannot do it using the backend, you may use yours site's database,

table #__extensions
column enabled

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Joomla 3.6 when adding SSL to my development server, and after lots of digging, determined I was a missing an Apache environment variable.

My solution was to add `SetEnv HTTPS on` to my Apache VirtualHost config, for all SSL domains.

Joomla queries the $_SERVER['HTTPS'] var to determine the url scheme, and falls back to http:// if that variable is not set. This can lead to a very confusing situation, where you're requesting a secure (https) url, but Joomla internally is converting the request to http, and then infinitely redirecting you to the secure URL – which you already requested in the first place!

The code that determines the URL scheme in Joomla is in /libraries/joomla/application/web.php, in the function detectRequestUri, which starts at around line 840.

If the HTTPS var isn't available on your system, and you don't have access to add it to your apache config, you can add an 'elseif' to check the $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] variable, which should be 443 for secure, and then set the scheme to https based on that. However, that would be hacking the Joomla core, and would definitely break on the next update, so that should definitely be a last resort.